# Find all points where the tangent line has slope 1.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)=x-\cos(x)$. Find all points on the graph of $y=f(x)$ where the tangent line has slope 1.  (In each answer $n$ varies among all integers).

So far I've used the Sum derivative rule for which I have $1+\sin(x)$. So do I put in 1 in for $x$ for sin$(x)$.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would set the derivative $1+\sin x=1$. So, the answer would be all $x$ satisfying the equation $\sin x = 0$, which is $x=k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct so far. Remember the derivative is the tangent line at any given point. So you have $y' = 1+sin(x)$. To find where the tangent line has slope 1 set $1+sin(x) = 1$. This will give you $sin(x)=0$. So all the points in which $x$ makes $sin(x)=0$

This means that $x = n\pi$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

You have to find all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, for which $f'(x) = 1$, so you are looking for solutions of equation $f'(x) = 1+ \sin x = 1$ or equivalnetly $\sin x = 0$. Therefore the answer is
$$x = k\pi\text{,}\quad k\in \mathbb{Z}\text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x - \cos x \tag{1}$

$f'(x) = 1 + \sin x \tag{2}$

$f'(x) = 1 \Rightarrow 1 = 1 + \sin x \Rightarrow \sin x = 0 \tag{3}$

$\sin x = 0 \Leftrightarrow  x = k\pi, \tag{4}$

for $k \in \Bbb Z$, the set of integers.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and, as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***